# как убрать лишние буквы начиная с определенной буквы во flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

например, есть `String` значение которого `public:123321` или `lock:123321`, и мне нужна только слова которые начинаются с первой буквы и заканчиваться до символа `:`, в итоге должно вывестись `public` или `lock`

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "public:123321";
print(str.split(":")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю пример с RegExp.

```
void main() {
  String str = "public:123321";
  print(str.replaceFirst(RegExp(r':.+'), ''));
}
```